# Intermediate node as a root node for dominator tree

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Can dominator trees be built with an intermediate node as the root node? ( Assuming that I am ignoring all the previous nodes in the original dominator tree while making this *new* tree? )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think dominator trees apply to compilers in general and not just Java.

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense -- the root node of the dominator tree is the root node.  Intermediate (non-root) nodes are not the root node.  You can build a tree rooted at some other node, but then it isn't a dominator tree.  There is exactly one dominator tree for a given control flow graph.

Answer (score 0):

The "dominance" property is defined in terms of all possible paths from the start node to a given node.

If you want to build a tree, rooted at some intermediate node N, you will have to devise another notion of "dominance", for example, node D dominates node S, if all possible paths from N to S pass trough D.

The problem here is that such a tree may not even exist, if there's no path from N to S.